# How to get the pin to show up on Google Maps URL

Tags: google-maps

My web application constructs a URL to go to Google Maps based on the lat and long of a place. Works great, however, the pin does not show up on the map of the location. For example, if I have this URL: https://www.google.com/maps/@39.0522772,-94.3865605,17z

Is there a specific parameter I need to pass in order for Google to show the pin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of query params [here](http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters) but it doesn't include showing a pin.

You can do this a couple of ways

Using preview

https://www.google.com/maps/preview?q=39.0522772,-94.3865605

Creating directions to and from the same place

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/39.0522772,-94.3865605/39.0522772,-94.3865605/@39.052269,-94.3885508,17z